# Why my xpath expression doesn't solved the question?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I practice in building xpath expression.
I found the following task:

> Select the small apple and the big orange

```
<div class='table'>
   <plate id="fancy">
       <apple class="small"/>
   </plate>
   <plate>
       <orange class="small"/>
       <orange/>
   </plate>
   <pickle class="small"/>
</div>
```

I can't understand why the following expression doesn't solve the question:

```
//apple[@class='small']|//orange[last()]
```

Comment: _small apple **and** the big orange_ : But `|` stands for **or**, what are you exactly looking for?

Comment: I think i need both of them. this is taken from the site:**https://topswagcode.com/xpath/** question 18

Comment: But how to play that... I'm still clueless :/

Comment: You must play with theirs rules :(
It means you must use last()

Comment: yeah :) now I can see the plates nudging with `//plate[position()=last()]`

Comment: I can't figure the answer :(

Comment: That was level 1 answer xpath :) For your question I have given the answer which is well tested as per the html you provided.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand what you are saying

Comment: Check my answer below to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is very opinionated, i.e. it does not accept all correct answers, but only specific ones.

What they want here is:

```
//plate[@id='fancy']/apple | //orange[last()]
```

Comment: So how did you figure the answer? Because this answer looks strange.. *plate* before *apple* but not before *orange*

Comment: It _is_ strange. I did a few of their previous problems and noticed the pattern of what they wanted :D

Answer (score 1):

To select the small apple and the big orange you need to use:

```
//apple[@class='small']|//orange[position()=last()]
```

Snapshot:

[image: small_apple_big_orange]

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how can i tested it on my computer (is this a specific web site in the screenshot)?